# online image dispatch on image view

Tags: ios

Online image speedily dispatch on Image-view.

```
dispatch_async(imageQueue, ^{
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:OBJPC.main_photo];
            NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url ];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [cell.imgTitle setImage:[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageData ]];
            });
        });
```

This leads me to believe the large images taken by the iPhone are timing out over the somewhat slow 3G network. Is there any way to compress/resize the image from the iPhone before sending it?

Thanks!

Comment: Basically you want to resize/compress images or what is your question?

Comment: NSData conversion take more time. i want to load image speedly.

Comment: That might be, does not answer my question... Do you want to LOAD or SEND images? What makes you believe it is slow? How large are your images?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,

If the photos are taken on iPhone 5S, 6+ they can be really large 10MB+.

before you upload the photos, use:

```
UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
```

where the image is a UIImage object and the compressionValue is a percentage.

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage, compressionValue);
```

Comment: unless you are talking about just downloading images from a URL in which case, this can only be done of the backend has a resizing functionality